Why does count parameter say the value needs to be less than or equal to -83
I have an array of indexes. These indexes are the first letter after a space in the given title parameter. I'd like to capitalize the first letter of each word after the spaces. I am also making all other characters in the original text parameter lowercase to show the text in title case for the returned text. This is what I have to do this
  public static string TitleCase(string title, string minorWords="")
  {
    title = title.ToLower();
    
    int[] indexes = new int[title.Length];
    
    indexes = Indexes(title);
    
    foreach(int i in indexes)
      {
        string sChar = new string(title[i].ToString());  
      
        title = title.Remove(title[i], 1);
      
        title = title.Insert(i, sChar.ToUpper());
      }
    
    return title;
  }

Once I reach
title.Remove(title[i], 1);

I get an error saying

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : count ('1') must be less than or
equal to '-83'. (Parameter 'count') Actual value was 1.

the stack trace is

at System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowGreater[T](T value, T
other, String paramName)    at System.String.Remove(Int32 startIndex,
Int32 count)    at Kata.TitleCase(String title, String minorWords)
at Solution.SolutionTest.MyTest(String sampleTitle, String
sampleMinorWords, String expected)    at
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void**
arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)    at
System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object
obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)


In .NET strings are immutable, so title.Remove(title[i], 1); and title.Insert(i, sChar.ToUpper()); don't modify title in any way.  Instead they return a new string.  You should re-examine your code with that in mind.

Also, might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Specifically, what is the value of the string title you are passing in?

Remove(title[i], 1); -> are you sure this shouldn't be Remove(i, 1);?

Thank you for the advice, I've modified the program for the minimal reproducible example and added return variables for my method calls.

Suggestion: create a StringBuilder (they are mutable). Size it )in the constructor) to be the same length as your string (so it doesn't need to be resized). Then create a small state machine that iterate over the characters in your string and builds the result you want in the StringBuilder. Don't use indexes, just the chars you get from the iteration

I apologize, I meant to close this out. Progman left the comment and it actually resolved all my issues. The program is working. Thank you all for your help and dilligence!
